# Angular 4 how to update value of class within callback function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pass-by-reference

I have this code where my "this.index" and "this.result" are undefined, how do I make it so that when I update their values it acts like pass by reference:

```
  submitQuiz(addsMemberPoints, pointsCallback) {
    this.getValues(this.answers, this.totalPoints, this.index, function(answers, totalPoints, ranks, index){
      pointsCallback(answers, ranks, addsMemberPoints, totalPoints, index, function(index, points){
        function getMember(obj) {
          return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b){ return obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b });
        }
        // would like to change index and result of initial class with new values
        this.result = getMember(points);
        this.index = index;
      });
    });

  }
```

The error that is created is reproduced
[image: here.]

Answer (score 0):

By using the 'that' trick.

```
submitQuiz(addsMemberPoints, pointsCallback) {
    var that = this;

    this.getValues(this.answers, this.totalPoints, this.index, function(answers, totalPoints, ranks, index){
      pointsCallback(answers, ranks, addsMemberPoints, totalPoints, index, function(index, points){
        function getMember(obj) {
          return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b){ return obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b });
        }
        // changed this to that
        that.result = getMember(points);
        that.index = index;
      });
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `arrow functions`?

Arrow functions do not lose the current `this` context allowing you to access it without defining `that` or `self` variables.

Check out this ES6 example and have a look at `getCommaSaperatedImages` function -

```js
class Hotel {

  constructor(images) {
    if (images && images.length) {
      this.images = images;
    }
  }

  getCommaSaperatedImages() {
    this.imageString = "";
    if (this.images && this.images.length) {
      this.images.forEach((image, index, images) => {
        //notice here `this` is still pointing to `Hotel` class.
        this.imageString += image.url;
        if (index === images.length - 1) {
          return;
        }
        this.imageString += ", ";
      });
    }
    return this.imageString;
  }
}

let hotel = new Hotel([{
  id: 1,
  url: 'http://image1.png'
}, {
  id: 2,
  url: 'http://image2.png'
}]);

console.log(hotel.getCommaSaperatedImages());
```

Typescript should work exactly the same.

I hope this helps :).

Comment: This is a correct answer, but since this is such a basic question that has already been answered, it's better to mark it as a duplicate so we don't have multiple sources of the same truth

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!!

Comment: @JuanMendes I think my reputation isn't sufficient enough to mark the question as duplicate. :|

Comment: I know, there are times that new people are tempted to leave an answer to get around some of the limitations imposed by SO. But there's a reason for the limitation in most cases :)